# How to solve a real time dwh delete process?

Tags: mysql, database, real-time, etl, data-warehouse

I am trying to create a near real time dwh. My first attempt is every 15 minutes load a table into my application from my DWH.

I would like to avoid all the possible problems that a near real time DWH can face. One of those problems is query an empty table that shows the value for a multiselect html tag.

To solve this I have thought the following solution but I do not know if there exists a standard to solve this kind of problem.

I create a table like this to save the possible values of the multiselect:

```
CREATE TABLE providers (
    provider_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    provider_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    delete_flag INT NOT NULL
)
```

Before the insert I update the table like this:

```
UPDATE providers set my_flag=1
```

I insert rows with an ETL process like this:

```
INSERT INTO providers (provider_name, delete_flag) VALUES ('Provider1',0)
```

From my app I query the table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT provider_name FROM providers
```

While the app still working and selecting all providers without duplicated (The source can delete, add or update one provider, so I always have to still updated respect the source) and without showing an error because table is empty I can run this statement just after the insert statement:

```
DELETE FROM providers WHERE delete_flag=1
```

I think that this is a good solution for small tables, or big tables with few changes, but what happens when a table is big? Exist some standard to solve this kind of problems?

We can not risk user usability because we are updating data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aproaches to publich a bulk change of a dimenstion without taking a maintainance window that would interupt the queries.

The first one is simple using a transactional concept, but performs bad for large data.

```
DELETE the replaced dimension records
INSERT the new or changed dimension records
COMMIT;
```

Note that you need no logical `DELETE` flag as the changes are visible only after the `COMMIT` - so the table is never empty.

As mentioned this approach is not suitable if you have a large dimension with lot of changes. In such case you may use the [EXCHANGE PARTITION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html)  feature as of MySQL 5.6

You define a temporary table with he same structure as your dimension table, that is partitioned with only one partition containing all data.

```
CREATE TABLE dim_tmp (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    col1 VARCHAR(30),
    col2 VARCHAR(30)
)
    PARTITION BY RANGE (id) (
        PARTITION pp VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

Populate the table with the complete new dimension definition and switch this temporary table with your dimension table.

```
 ALTER TABLE dim_tmp EXCHANGE PARTITION pp WITH TABLE dim;
```

After this statement the data from the temporary table will be stored (published) in your dimension table (new definition) and the old state of the dimension will be stored in the temporary table.

Please check the documentation link above for constraints of this feature.

Disclaimer: I use this feature in Oracle DB and I have no experience with it in MySQL.

Comment: your first solution is good. But in SQL server the commit statement needs to be activated, by default it does the commit. The second solution i understand the concept but what is the functionality of the partition here?

Comment: Partition is used from technical reasons. You may switch a partition against a table - not a table with a table. Pleas check doku.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!